# Sctp и защита от syn-flood атаки

Tags: сеть, сетевое-программирование

Не могу понять, как решается этот вопрос в sctp.  В tcp syn атака заключается в том что посылаем множество syn пакетов, сервер открывает новый сокет и отправляет syn-ack а мы дальше не отвечаем. И так пока сервер не откажется обслуживать новые соединения. В sctp ввели 4х рукопожатие, ну и что? Я могу так же посылать init и не отвечать. Будет такой же эффект

Comment: syn-flood от одного источника (ip) легко отследить и заблокировать. поэтому для атаки используется множество адресов отправителя. в случае tcp один и тот же хост может ставить произвольные адреса отправителя и больше ни о чем не заботиться, потому что ему не надо получать ответы. В случае с sctp отправитель должен указать свой настоящий адрес, потому что ему надо будет получить куку и выслать ее обратно, иначе сервер не будет ничего хранить об этом соединении. Так что опасность syn-flood в принципе есть, но она не столь масштабна